# Cant install ubuntu 14.10amd 64 alongside windows10 home edition

Tags: dual-boot, 14.10

I am running windows 10 home edition 64 bit on hp laptop with SSD. I tried installing ubuntu 14.10amd64 alongside using USB but it doesnt identify any drive on my pc and show error message and stops installation. Also I cannot run ubuntu inside windows using same usb flash drive and or by using iso file. I have created separate drive for installation of the ubuntu. Hp envy touchsmart sleekbook4 ck82ua#abl. 
i have only one ssd and Windows UEFI and fast startup and secure boots are disabled –

error observed is table having headings 
"Device   Type     Mountpoint       format?      Size      Used     System "

Whcih doesnt have any entry below it has symbpl "+-" followed by "change"

Below it is having drop down button having only one menu

Device for bootloader installation 
/dev/sda
when i clicked install now  it displayed message 
No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
and further it quits the program.

Please help. I am very new to the Linux operating system and dont know much of the programming or terms like root or etc.
@biozalp now m having it formatted in windows now what should i do?

Comment: you got one hdd/ssd right? you have to turnoff fastboot first.  http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Dear biozalp i have only one ssd and Windows UEFI and fast startup and secure boots are disabled

Comment: created an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

First go to diskmgmt.msc in windows (win+r), than shrink your partition as much as you want, leave it nonformatted, go back to ubuntu installation, choose something else, format and flag the empty space you have created in windows like [the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation), afterwards you should be ready to go.

Comment: Remember he needs to make a swap partition too

Comment: the link provides that step as well, /, /home, /swap will be created in the instructive page "the link", i just made him to avoid damaging windows files by shrinking via disk management tool in windows, something else will be followed afterwards

Comment: Nice, sorry I didn't see the link. :)