# No option coming to install ubuntu alongwith existing os which is windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu with my existing Windows 10 and trying to create a dual boot up!

My machine is hp envy and I have went to the Bios to disable the secure boot option as well!

One of my device drive partition is entirely free which I have reserved for ubuntu, but nothing shows up to install ubuntu with current Os.

Comment: You may need to use the manula option , aka Something else, and set up partitions manually.

Comment: Can you confirm if you've installed both OS's in UEFI or BIOS mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/695022/cant-install-ubuntu-14-10amd-64-alongside-windows10-home-edition

Answer (score 0):

First, it's ***IMPERATIVE*** that you disable the Windows "Fast Startup" feature. Doing so is covered [here,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) among other places. Note that this feature is *not* the same as a feature with a similar name in many EFIs' setup utilities.

Second, Secure Boot is not likely to be a problem. Disabling it won't make things any harder, but doing so will probably not make them any easier, either. There are exceptions, but this isn't the universally-necessary step that so many people think it is.

Third, the "install alongside" option is often missing on modern EFI-based computers. I'm not sure of the technical cause. (Maybe just the Windows Fast Startup feature, maybe something else.) You may need to use the "something else" option instead, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8) (again, among many other places).

Finally, many HPs have broken EFIs that will give you problems. I can't say for certain that *all* HPs are broken, but if the computer is new and you end up booting straight into Windows when you're done, save yourself further headaches and return it to the store for a refund. If the computer is old enough that this is impossible, there are workarounds; see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file) (once again, or many other places) for the ugly details.